# Why does 1 === (1..12) evaluate to false, while (1..12) === 1 evaluates to true?

Tags: ruby, expression, range

I was testing a snippet of code, then I found this:

```
2.1.2 :016 > 1 === (1..12)
 => false
2.1.2 :017 > (1..12) === 1
 => true
2.1.2 :018 >
```

Why does the order matter in this boolean expression?

Comment: `===` is just a garden-variety method with an unusual name.  For a given method `m`, would you expect `1.m(1..12) == (1..12).m(1)`?  No.

Comment: Consider this, `===` is saying "is the object on the right an instance of the class on the left and/or contained by it?". So, is `1` an instance of `1..12` and/or contained by it? Yes. Is `1..12` an instance or contained by `1`? No.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `==` is also a method.

Comment: Some methods are symmetric, most are not.  The only reason you think `===` (as opposed to `some_method`) should be symmetric is because it resembles the method `==`, which is. Close only counts in horseshoes.

Comment: `===` is just a method of an object on the left side and object on the right side is an argument. In the first case it's `Fixnum#===` ie. whether argument equals numerically whereas the second case is `Range#===` which returns true if argument is an element of the range. So you are comparing apples & oranges here.